# jspdf TypeError: this.margins is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, export

When I am trying to implement the script to export to PDF from html table using these below functions, I am getting this error.

**jspdf TypeError: this.margins is undefined**

Please help me to resolve my problem. Thanks.

```
function exportTable()
{
    var table = tableToJson($('#test').get(0))
        var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4', true);
        doc.cellInitialize();
        $.each(table, function (i, row){
            console.debug(row);
            $.each(row, function (j, cell){
                doc.cell(10, 50,120, 50, cell, i);  // 2nd parameter=top margin,1st=left margin 3rd=row cell width 4th=Row height
            })
        })
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];
    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }
    // go through cells
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};
        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
        data.push(rowData);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it when I use the jspdf.pluin.cell.js from below link

https://code.google.com/p/bdd-biocomp/source/browse/trunk/js/jspdf/jspdf.plugin.cell.js?r=129